# Deps.autorun says server function is undefined

Tags: meteor

I've never took the time/chance to really understand the scope of Deps.autorun... so here I am again with the same problem that had bothered me many times (previously, I always found a workaround and bypass the issue)... anyways, basically, I have a function defined on the server side:

```
serverFunc = function() {}
```

and on the client side, I do

```
Deps.autorun(function() { var test = serverFunc(); }
```

I get error message say serverFunc is not defined.

Can someone kindly help me understanding why this is happening?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

`Deps.autorun()` always runs once, then reruns the function whenever any of the dependencies that are tracked changes.  These dependencies usually need to be set up as Meteor reactive data sources. A simple function being undefined on the client and then defined on the server isn't enough to retrigger.

If you want functions defined only on the server to be called from the client, you have to do two things:

1. On the server, put the function in [`Meteor.methods`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods)
2. On the client, use [`Meteor.call`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call)

Otherwise, a function defined only on the server does not exist on the client, and calling it on the client will throw an error as calling an undefined function.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of that... however, I can call serverFunc in my template function such as: Template.menu.test = function() { serverFunc(); }, it works... so what is the difference? I believe Deps.autorun is running on a totally different scope, but how is it different?

Comment: Defining a template that calls a non-existent function is a bug, just as putting a non-existent function into Deps.autorun.  The difference is that Deps.autorun is always run once on startup, whereas the template might never run.  The internal error handling might also be different, on that I don't know and suggest testing.